# angular router URL always points to home on initial load

Tags: angular, angular-router

When doing initial load of angular app, router.url always points to home URL ('/').
Even if I open app with domain/some-route, the route url is '/'.

Here is the code:

constructor(private router: Router) {}

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.router.url);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.router.url);
  }, 100);
}
```

After timeout (of 100ms) the URL is correct.

See [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epv4wn?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

On preview load this as initial path: https://angular-epv4wn.stackblitz.io/home
and check the console.

SetTimeout is workaround solution, but I don't want to rely on this.

Comment: `NavigationEnd` you need to detect this event like in this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ime53m?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: This works, however it works on every route change. I need only initial load url.

Comment: use take(1) after filter in pipe(). It will unsubscribe observable automatically after first emit

Answer (score 1):

the router has many events, NavigationStart, GuardsCheck, RoutesRecognized, ResolveRoute...
you are interested in NavigationEnd because it will give  the correct path if it exist in the router or the fallback one

so you need to wait for navigation to finish...

```
 this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      )
      .subscribe(url=> {
        console.log(this.router.url)
        console.log(event.url);
      });
```

both console will give you /home

Comment: This works, however it works on every route change. I need only initial load url.

Comment: on pipe add take(1) on manually unsubscribe when you don't need anymore